# How to make pocketsphinx ignore words that are not present in the dictionary

Tags: pocketsphinx

I have a list of keywords that need to be spotted but some words are not "real words" (abracadabra, for example) and obviously they aren't in the dictionary.

My question is how do I ignore them ? 
(pocketsphinx returns an ERROR and stops). I read a manual for pocketsphinx_continuous but didn't find a suitable parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using a word in a keyphrase check if it is in the dictionary with `ps_lookup_word`.

Comment: in my opinion, it makes more sense to skip them (or display in error section but not stop the program), or make a command line option for that, like --ignore_missing.